How can I test if a command fails or returns a certain output?
I have a bash script with a command and I want to test if a command fails or returns an output that matches an regex. Something like this:
commandOutput = command()

if (commandOutput.exitCode = ERROR or commandOutput.matches(string|strong) then
    doStuffOnError()
end

How can I do this in a shell script?

As stated in the man page for Bash: `?
Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.`

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] || [ "$commandOutput" = "string" ] || [ "$commandOutput" = "strong" ]; then doStuffOnError; else dontDoStuffOnError; fi

Does this answer your question? Capturing output and exit codes in BASH / SHELL

Since you ask specifically for BASH code, I'll use [[]] which is only available in BASH.
You can do what you want by using the following code:
commandOutput=$(command)
if [[ $? -ne 0 || $commandOutput == *"string"* || $commandOutput == *"strong"* ]]; then
    doStuffOnError
fi
    

Explanations:

$? in shell is the exit code of the previous command
we check if it is non-zero (aka it ended with an error) or if the output matches "string" or "strong", if any of those is true then we execute duStuffOnError

Note that here the commandOutput only stores what is on stdout.
If you want also stderr, consider commandOutput=$(command 2>&1) which redirects stderr to stdout.

Why is testing $? to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern? A better formulation might be if commandOutput=$(command) && [[ $commandOutput = *"str"[io]"ng"* ]]

@tripleee Right, I didn't think of it, but generally I prefer to declare/initialize variables on their own separate lines. Also, if you are going that way, remember we are checking if the command exited with error (and in Shell, zero-exit code are considered as "true"). So you should negate the exit status with !: if ! commandOutput=$(command) && [[ $commandOutput = *"str"[io]"ng"* ]]

Uh, what? That would only proceed if the command failed.

Yeah, read the OP title question: How can I test if a command fails or returns a certain output?. So if the command exited with an non-zero error code, or if its output matches "string" or "strong", we should execute doStuffOnError as asked by OP;

I did a mistake in my first reply sorry. It should be || not &&. if ! commandOutput=$(command) || [[ $commandOutput = *"str"[io]"ng"* ]]. I tested it this time.    Also this is a perfect example of why I prefer declaring the variables on their own separate lines, to keep the code clean and easier to read/understand.

I endet up with this solution, thank you! I added $ to the variables in the if: $commandOutput == *"string"* || $commandOutput == *"strong"* - otherwise I got a syntax error.

The [[]] construct, along with the =~ operator, enables Bash to perform regex matching and return the matched portions. Like this example below -
if [[ "$line" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then

